# MySQL JOIN Row Exists But Does Not Match Where Statement

Tags: mysql

Below is 2 tables and a select statement I am trying to make work, but I ran into an issue. Can someone please look this over and help me out. (details below)

**Table `company_locatons`**

```
id | company_id | location  | deleted
1  | 1          | Las Vegas | 0
```

**Table `location_images`**

```
id | location_id | image                                 | deleted
1  | 1           | company-name.las-vegas.1531516751.jpg | 1
2  | 1           | company-name.las-vegas.1531516752.jpg | 1
3  | 1           | company-name.las-vegas.1531516753.jpg | 1
```

**Select Statement:**

```
SELECT `cl`.*, ifnull(li.image, "") AS image 
FROM `company_locations` `cl` 
LEFT JOIN `location_images` `li` 
    ON `li`.`location_id` = `cl`.`id` 
WHERE (`li`.`deleted` =0 OR `li`.`id` IS NULL) 
    AND `cl`.`deleted` =0 
ORDER BY `rating` DESC
```

If the `location_images` table had no records for the company location, it returns perfectly, but since there are records and they don't match the where I get no results.

Edit:

**Expected Output**

```
cl.id | cl.company_id | cl.location  | image | cl.deleted
1     | 1             | Las Vegas    | NULL  | 0
```

Comment: You need to move the WHERE condition to the ON in the LEFT JOIN.. Or the LEFT JOIN will be rewritten to a INNER JOIN by the MySQL optimizer.

Comment: I am confused by the question. If your where is not returning the results you want, then why is it your where?

Comment: Could you give some expect result?

Comment: Could you add excepted output

Comment: I added the expected output to the post. I will also look into Raymond's suggestion of pulling the image from a SELECT in the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` statement is filtering everything in `location_images` with

```
 `li.deleted =0`
```

However, all the records in your `location_images` is set to `1`. Then it's normal not to return anything. Please update the records in your `location_images` and set
`deleted=0` in order for the query to run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem thanks to a suggestion by Raymond Nijland.

```
SELECT `cl`.*, ifnull(li.image, "") AS image 
FROM `company_locations` `cl` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, location_id, image FROM location_images WHERE deleted = 0) `li`
    ON (`li`.`location_id` = `cl`.`id` OR `li`.`id` IS NULL) 
WHERE `cl`.`deleted` =0 
ORDER BY `rating` DESC
```

I really should have guessed this was the solution, but I forgot that I could add an `OR` to the JOIN ON.